# How does React perform on mobile compared to vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm a beginning developer and I'm thinking of making an ionic app using React, but I'm worried that the increased memory usage from the virtual DOM may hurt the UX on lower end devices. Would React work better, because of less rendering or worse because there's more memory needed. The app I'm thinking about making probably won't be particularly memory intensive in general, but I'm not sure how React would affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VanillaJS will always be faster. React includes VDOM, SyntheticEvent, and other stuffs into their library. It is only logical that you are using more memory by adding stuffs.

BUT, what the VDOM allows you to do is to do updates more efficiently. VDOM is a representation of the DOM in the memory. Think of it like a tree of a lot of JS objects referencing each other, forming what is representing the DOM tree.

Now, let's say you are updating one of your component state. React uses the VDOM to find the components that will need to be updated by that state change. More than one component might need to be updated. After doing the updates to the VDOM, it then commits the changes to the actual DOM. Updating the DOM is quite expensive, but operating on VDOM is cheap. This is why all the updates are applied to the VDOM first before finally committed to the actual DOM. If you were to implement the same mechanism using vanilla JS, it will probably take quite a long time to do so.

If performance on lower end devices is an absolute priority, there is [Preact](http://preactjs.com/) that is very similar to React, with only 3 kB runtime size (depending on what you use). Another interesting UI framework you might want to look at is [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/), which compiles your code into frameworkless, vanilla JS.